# How can I delete child rows when I delete parent row withour declaring child variables

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm currently working on a SQL project. I want to make a stored procedure to delete rows in my database. The only problem is that when I delete a row, there are multiple child rows who use the variable. I will first give some context. I have a database who stored taxi rides. Here are the tables I use to delete (i left some of the columns away to make is more clear)

```
create table User
(

    (primary key)UserID         int,
)

create table Rating
(


    (primary key)RatingID       int,
    (foreign key)UserID         int,
)

create table Complaint
(


    (primary key)ComplaintID        int,
    (foreign key)RatingID       int,
)
```

This is the stored procedure I made for deleting the user. How can I delete the row complaint (who has a relation with Rating > User)? Do I need to declare the ratingID somewhere?

```
create procedure SPDeleteUser
(
    @UserID int,
)
as
begin 
begin transaction

select UserID from Rating
delete from Complaint where UserID = @UserID

select UserID from Rating
delete from Rating where UserID = @UserID

select UserID from User
delete from User where UserID = @UserID

if @@ERROR <> 0
begin
rollback transaction
raiserror('Can't delete the user make sure the values are correct', 16, 
1)
return
end

commit
end
go
```

How do I fix it that the rows(relation User>Rating and Rating>complaint) automatically will be deleted when I enter the UserID?

EDIT!
Fixed it with ON DELETE CASCADE. Now I Only have the next delete statements.

```
delete from Rating where UserID = @UserID
delete from User where UserID = @UserID
```

With the ON DELETE CASCADE constraint it automatically deletes the Complaint rows. Thanks for the help! Still need to improve on my code skills

Comment: There are many things broken here. First of all your EXISTS have no where clause so they are pretty pointless. You have basically said, if there are any rows at all in the table then delete just these rows. I would just delete the rows instead of first checking for them and then deleting them. Also, the error message you stated would not happen with the code posted. RatingID is nowhere in this code. Last but not least, your raiserror is invalid because what you posted contains a single quote in the middle of your string literal.

Comment: And look at your first delete statement. You check to see if there are any rows in Rating and if there are you delete from a different table. There is also a random select statement that retrieves all the UserID values from the User table.

Comment: You also couldn't be getting the error you say you are getting, since "RatingID" doesn't appear anywhere in the code you posted.   Unless you also have a trigger on one of these tables..

Comment: Looks like you could benefit from `ON DELETE CASCADE` on your foreign keys...

Answer (score 2):

The code you posted is kind of all over the place. It sort of deals with transactions, well it rolls one back but doesn't start one. That would cause an error. The error you have it pretty worthless because if you encounter an error on either of the first two deletes you will miss it like this.

Pretty sure you are looking for something along these lines.

```
create procedure SPDeleteUser
(
    @UserID int
)
as
begin 

    set nocount on;

    begin transaction

    begin try

        --select UserID from Rating
        delete from Complaint where UserID = @UserID

        --select UserID from Rating
        delete from Rating where UserID = @UserID

        --select UserID from [User]
        delete from [User] where UserID = @UserID

        commit transaction
    end try

    begin catch
        rollback transaction
        raiserror('Can''t delete the user make sure the values are correct', 16, 1) 
        --just my 2¢ but this error is useless. It does not provide any details about what is actually wrong.
        --Instead you should get the actual error message and raise that so you know what the problem is. 
    end catch

end
```